# Composer rest server multiuser: Error trying to login and get user Context

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I did the following tutorial: https://www.codementor.io/gangachris125/passport-jwt-authentication-for-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-jqfgkoljn

Now I completed everything and I imported a user card into the wallet. But now when I try to make a API request to an endpoint, I get this output:

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 500,
        "name": "Error",
        "message": "Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{\"code\":20,\"message\":\"Authorization failure\"}]]",
        "stack": "Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{\"code\":20,\"message\":\"Authorization failure\"}]]\n    at HLFConnection.login (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:477:30)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)"
    }
}
```

Already searched for a solution but couldn't find anyone.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

1) export the card

```
composer card export -c admin@network -f admin-plus-cert.card
```

2) delete the old card

```
composer card delete -c admin@network
```

3) import the new card

```
composer card import -f admin-plus-cert.card
```